# How to assign a runnable to android button in main class?

Tags: android, runnable

I am working on my homework project and I am stuck. I've created a simple application with few textfields and four buttons- calculate, reset,about,exit. For this purpose I've started a thread "calculation". The idea is user feeds in some values in designated text fileds, presses calculate and the results appear in other fields.And I want to run the entire calculation in the main class and here's a section of my code-

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.about_button:
         Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
         startActivity(i);
         break;
      // More buttons go here (if any) ...
      case R.id.exit_button:
         finish();
         break;
      case R.id.reset_button:
          clearAllFields();
          break;
      case R.id.calculate_button:
          startCalculation ();
          break;}}
void  startCalculation() {
     calculation = new Thread(this);
     calculation.start();}
```

but when i run and press calculation the app force closes.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you feeding in `this` into the Constructor of `Thread` ? You should be looking at your stack trace when an app crashes because it will give you clues as to where (and why) your app crashed.

Comment: @Marvin Pinto--I'm allowed to use runnable only.

Comment: @Graeme Well I removed this from the constructor. The app ran and didn't crash but it didn't calculate either.

Comment: @user1149621 Could you please **edit** your post and include the rest of your code? It will give us a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: Post your LogCat Error Log. That is where the real information on why it is force closing is found

Answer (score 0):

I always do it this way:

```
this.hiButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.HI);
  this.hiButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      sayHalloYouWonderfulWorldOfAndroid();
    }
  });
```

Comment: And usually using the lazy pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
void  startCalculation() {
 calculation = new Thread(this);*
 calculation.start();}
```

- This piece of code makes constructs a new thread with the argument `this`. As you can see from the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) this will mean when you call `start()` it will simply call the `run()` method of the argument you fed into the constructor. Unless you have an overridden `run()` method in `this` ...

If you want a Thread to actually do any work then you should give it a no arguments constructor and override the run method, creating an anonymous class. You do this like so:

```
Thread calculation = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Do calculation here
}
```

To get the answer to display on your page you should use a `Handler`. But you can look that up your very own self :)